# How to connect with TFS and get list of projects for a specific user

Tags: c#, tfs

```
public List<string> ListAllProjects(){    
TeamFoundationServer teamFoundationServer =
     TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer(@"http:\\ld-tfs08sp1:8080\\");    

teamFoundationServer.Authenticate();    
WorkItemStore workItemStore = new WorkItemStore(@"http:\\ld-tfs08sp1:8080\\");    

List<string> list = new List<string>();    

foreach (Project pr in workItemStore.Projects)    
{
        list.Add(pr.Name);    
}    

if (list.Count == 0)        
      list.Add("Not Found");    

return list;

}
```

Comment: Is there a question here, or are you just providing a sample?

Comment: This only works for the TFS 2008 API. With 2010 you need to connect to a Team Project Collection

Answer (score 18):

Here is an example that will retrieve a list of Team Projects for a given Team Project Collection (TPC) in TFS 2010:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var results = GetTfsProjects(new Uri("http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
}

private static List<string> GetTfsProjects(Uri tpcAddress)
{
    var tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tpcAddress);

    tpc.Authenticate();

    var workItemStore = new WorkItemStore(tpc);
    var projectList = (from Project pr in workItemStore.Projects select pr.Name).ToList();

    return projectList;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works perfectly here after I removed the tfs/DefaultCollection part from the URI (different version of TFS perhaps?)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var TeamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(teamProjectCollectionUrl);
var commonStruct = TeamProjectCollection.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();
var teamProjectInfos = commonStruct.ListAllProjects();
```

good luck