# TFS folder browsing

Tags: tfs

I'm creating a tool that needs to browse for folders into TFS. In other words, I want the user to be able to select a folder within projects in TFS.

Also I found a [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413527/how-to-connect-with-tfs-and-get-list-of-projects-for-a-specific-user/12644066#12644066) posted by Jeff Bramwell. It does most of the work but I would like to be able to allow the user to select folders within TFS.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's an internal api to popup a dialog, it's not supported but you can use it.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/molausson/archive/2010/10/21/browse-items-in-tfs-version-control-programmatically-reposted.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know by chance if there is another API or method that would allow me to access folders located in the Team Explorer. For example the Team Queries folder.

Comment: I dont' know it off the top of my head sorry