# Getting "subprojects" (teams?) in TFS 2012

Tags: c#, tfs

[Similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413527/how-to-connect-with-tfs-and-get-list-of-projects-for-a-specific-user), I want to get all projects listed under a user. I'm currently working with the code from the link before:

```
private static List<string> GetTfsProjects(Uri tpcAddress)
{
    var tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tpcAddress);

    tpc.Authenticate();

    var workItemStore = new WorkItemStore(tpc);
    var projectList = (from Project pr in workItemStore.Projects select pr.Name).ToList();

    return projectList;
}
```

..but it's only returning "LSWebsite" (my URI is `h ttp://server:port/defaultcollection`). How do I get LSWebsite and its children? Image below shows the hierarchy I'm currently working with.

[image: Sample hierarchy image]

Comment: Those are not subprojects, those are teams in TFS 2012. The `TfsTeamService` object may be of some use to figure this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.tfsteamservice.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those look like teams.

Try this snippet:

```
var teamService = tpc.GetService<TfsTeamService>();

var teams =
        projectList
        .SelectMany(
            projectId =>
                teamService
                .QueryTeams(projectId)
                .Select(t =>  String.Format("{0}\\{1}", projectId, t.Name)))
        .ToArray();

projectList.AddRange(teams);
```

Taken from Shai's blog [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2012/05/20/tfs-api-part-44-vs11-teams-and-team-members.aspx).

Comment: Hey, thanks. I tried this out and it worked right away. Still trying to figure out some of the terminology in TFS, so I wasn't sure, but I'm glad you were!